# Regex exclude closing bracket

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking to match the final number inside a set of square brackets in a string and pull it out for use elsewhere

```
[PROJECT-141] This is the task name
^^ Should get **141**
[PROJECT2-222] Let's be tricky and add an extra number 22
^^ Should get **222**
```

I have a regex which is pretty close - it picks up the final number. But it's also including the closing `]` in the match. I've fiddled around with match groups, but with no joy.

This is going into a Ruby project when it works. Here's the best I have so far:

```
\[*(\d+)\]
```

It matches:

```
141]
222]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do using [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method :

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

```
'[PROJECT2-222]'[/\[.*-(\d+)\]/,1] # => "222"
'[PROJECT-141]'[/\[.*-(\d+)\]/,1] # => "141"
```

Comment: the regex seems quite similar :) Upvoted, as I was not aware about the `String#[]` method. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
project_ids = [
"[PROJECT-141] This is the task name",
"[PROJECT2-222] Let's be tricky and add an extra number 22",
].map { |s|
  s[/-(\d+)\]/, 1]
} 
project_ids # => ["141", "222"]
```

This is the sort of task a regex is designed for. `\d` is a digit, 0..9. `\d+` is one or more digits. We need some place-holders to figure out where in the string to search, so using `-` which precedes the number, and `]` which follows it, is sufficient for the examples given.

The magic occurs in the `map` block, using `s[/-(\d+)\]/, 1]`, which is a simple way of saying:

1. Look inside the string for something matching the pattern.
2. The capture group `(\d+)` tells the engine to remember that part of the pattern, which is then returned using the `1` parameter. It's all part of [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 0):

### My Take:

try this regex: `/\[.*-(\d+)\]/`

Here is the console tryout inside `pry` for **the above regex**:

```
[1] pry(main)> str = "[PROJECT-141] This is the task name"
# => "[PROJECT-141] This is the task name"
[2] pry(main)> match = str.match(/\[.*-(\d+)\]/)
#=> #<MatchData "[PROJECT-141]" 1:"141">
[3] pry(main)> match[1]
#=> 141
```

---

### Your Take:

Also, your regex is correct too. Only difference is that it matches `141]`, but the first match, i.e. `match[1]` will give you the required integers, i.e. `141`.

Here is the console tryout inside `pry` for **your regex**:

```
[4] pry(main)> str = "[PROJECT-141] This is the task name"
# => "[PROJECT-141] This is the task name"
[5] pry(main)> match = str.match(/\[*(\d+)\]/)
#=> #<MatchData "141]" 1:"141">
[6] pry(main)> match[1]
#=> 141
```

---

### Probably, a function? :P

Here is a quick function you can create using the above:

```
# will output 0, if it could not find a match for the project's id
def extract_project_ids(*args)
  args.map { |task| task.match(/\[.*-(\d+)\]/)[1] rescue 0 }
end

task1 = "[PROJECT-141] This is the task name"
task2 = "[PROJECT2-222] Let's be tricky and add an extra number 22"
extract_project_ids(task1, task2)
# => [ 141, 222 ]
```